# Reactjs - react router : My css and scripts only load for the first time for nested children route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

hi I'm new to react and trying to use react-router to navigate my apps
I have index.html with my css and script like this

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

  <title>My Apps</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/angular-material.min.css">
  <link id="app_main_css" rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/main.css">

  <script src="/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body data-ng-app="app" id="app" data-custom-background="" data-off-canvas-nav="" data-ng-controller="MyController">
<div id="root"></div>

<script id="app_js" type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/app.js"></script>

</body>
```

my route look like this

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={MasterPage}>
      <IndexRoute component={Dashboard} />
      <Route path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
      <Route path='/dashboard1' component={Dashboard1} />
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

when first time load the css and scripts went well, my dashboard show up as expected, but when I navigate to let's say Dashboard1 the css and script won't load, and then when I navigate back to Dashboard it also not loaded.
so the css and scripts only load for the first time.
How do I make it so that nested child pages also could load the main css ?

Comment: Why do you want the css to reload when its already loaded the first time ? the css for nested components should also be in the same main css file.

Comment: because in my case when navigate to another child page using <Link>, it  won't load css/script for that js

Comment: All your css across the whole application should be bundled into a single css file because when navigating via Link, the window is not refreshed and only the front-end application is updated OR If you want the page to refresh and load css again use the a tag instead of Link.